# Using selenium and python to visit multiple sites

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm new to programming and I was just messing around with selenium. I started simple by using it to visit a website. It got me thinking, how would one visit multiple sites, specifically one after the other? How would I go about doing that in Python?

I guess what I'm asking is how would I use selenium to visit a list of sites one after another, waiting about 10 seconds in between going to the sites.

Here's what I have so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='PATH_TO_WEBDRIVER')

url = "http://www.google.com"

driver.get(url)
print(driver.title)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `list` of urls to visit:

```
urls = ['http://www.google.com','https://stackoverflow.com']
```

Loop the `list` of urls:

```
for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    print(driver.title)
    time.sleep(10)
```

**Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='PATH_TO_WEBDRIVER')
urls = ['http://www.google.com','https://stackoverflow.com']

for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    print(driver.title)

driver.close()
```

**Output**

```
Google
Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This looks like it'll work.

Comment: @LearningGuy15 don't forget to close/quite driver

Answer (score 0):

To add to HedgeHog's response, should you want to visit websites in succession and the links are not known in advance (example, going to a newspaper and then the link(s) of the first article/first suggested article), I'd follow something like:

```
driver.get(url)
driver.get(driver.find_element_by_xpath(new_link))
```